# ajax .load function removes whole page and only loads single image

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making my personal webpage that features fancy jQuery slide function to show and hide multiple pages. It works well but I have to consider for people who browses with their javascript disabled. That means I can't use jQuery function to hide and show pages. At the moment, no-javascript users will see all pages at once. So I want modify the page that will display and functions correctly with some pages hidden for javascript and non-javascript users.

I have devised a method to achieve this but I will need to use ajax or something else to load those hidden pages on javascript load and hide it. I tried to use ajax .load to load page fragment stored in a file but it just throws the whole page away and displays one of the images in the page fragment code.

This is code I used to load the page

```
$('#resume').load("include/mywork.php");
```

The mywork.php file looks something like this. (Simplified)

```
<h1>My work</h1>
<div>
     <noscript><!--For non-javascript users -->
          <img class="insideIMG" src='images/works/worklogo.png' alt=''>
     </noscript>
     <script><!-- lazy loading plugin for javascript users -->
          document.write("<img class='insideIMG' src='images/loading.gif' data-echo='images/works/worklogo.jpg' alt=''>);
     </script>
     comments comments comments lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Does anyone else know what's causing the javascript to remove whole page and only display the image?

Comment: Probably `document.write(...)`, since that's exactly what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `document.write` is used on a document that has been closed, it empties the document and writes new content to it. That is what happens in your case since the script is executed AFTER the document is done loading. Your only real option is to not use `document.write` to create that image.

```
<h1>My work</h1>
<div>
     <img class='insideIMG' src='images/loading.gif' data-echo='images/works/worklogo.jpg' alt=''>
     comments comments comments lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: yup, that's the culprit. Thanks for catching that.